# How get variable from ajax in another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The problem is when I click on "submit data" button I get the response (this is correct), but when I click on "go to the php file" link (which is the same php file as previously) I get Undefined index: firstname and Undefined index: lastname error. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function ajax_post(){
            // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
            var url = "my_parse_file.php";
            var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
            var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
            var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
            hr.open("POST", url, true);
            // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
            }
            // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
            hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
    First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
    Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
    <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <a href="my_parse_file.php">go to the php file</a>
</body>
```

and the php file

```
<?php 

echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', says the PHP file';

?>
```

Comment: you are going to the php file on a get request (`href`) and so it's a different request..

Comment: you need to post parameters to the php

Comment: The second time when you hit 'go to php file', it will be a GET request, and php won't find those variables in the $_POST superglobal.

Comment: either use a form to post it with POST, or add the parameters to a query string in the link and retrieve them with GET. either way, what you're doing does not require ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Because both are different requests :**

As you are passing parameters `firstname` and `lastname` using AJAX. You have to pass the same in `URL` using `GET` request.

go to the php file

```
<?php 

echo 'Thank you '. $_REQUEST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_REQUEST['lastname'] . ', says the PHP file';

?>
```

**Output :**

Thank you `abc` `xyz`, says the PHP file

It will work in both `Submit button` and `Hyperlink`.

Comment: Using `$_REQUEST` is always a bad idea, except some very rare cases. This is not one of that. You **SHOULD** know, where your data is come from.

Comment: Thanks for the update..As i am not so good in PHP can you please update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking the link your browser sends not a POST request, but a GET request to your server-side. That is why the global array $_POST doesn't contains the elements you are trying to retrieve in your PHP file. The error message points you that there is no such elements in the $_POST array like "firstname" and "lastname".
It is recommended to add a check whether the array elements exist like so:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
        echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', says the PHP file';
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing to say';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks R J for explanation. Now i fixed it and works properly.

But I am worried, because i used this code only for training. In my main problem i need to send the real object (not string etc.) by ajax to my php site, so i cant add it to the url, can I?